Micro Front End : How to not cache the remoteEntry.js and using hash how effectively can we improve the performance without calling bundles everytime
We have a react application and we are using module federation with webpack to load the Micro Front End.
We have tried the
    output: {
  filename: 'bundle.[contenthash].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},

Also we have set the max-age for remoteEntry.js as 0.
It works but sometimes we have seen that for few bundle hashed files it tries to call the server even though there is no change in hash.
What is the best way to achieve this? If there is no change in hash value then it should not take time or load from disk cache then.
